How to keep single quotes when importing CSV file in Postgres
I am trying to import a CSV file that contains a bunch of single-quotes in PostgreSQL 16 and I wanted to preserve the single quotes as they are in the data.
I am using PgAdmin-4's Import/Export Data... window and currently I am dealing with configuring the Options tab:

I tried setting up the Quote and Escape options as follows but got the same error:

Quote (') and Escape (")
Quote (') and Escape (')


I am thinking to try to reverse the values to make the Quote value double (") and the Escape be single ('), but that would mean replacing the single-quotes in the CSV file by double-quotes, which would be difficult to do.
For reference, here is a sample of what the specific column/field that contains strings with single-quotes in the CSV file's table looks like:

Is there a way I can still import the data as it is?
Answer
As advised by @AdrianKlaver in the Comments section, I kept the default Options setting, which is double-quotes (") for both the Quote and Escape characters. I also left the CSV file with the single-quotes as is. Then I was able to import just fine.
Follow-up question
Seems that the double-quote designation in the Quote parameter does not replace single-quotes in the data getting imported. If so, what is the use setting up the Quote and Escape options?

You absolutely must share a sample of this CSV in the question otherwise all you are going to get is guesses. The parameters of the import are entirely 100% based on the specs of the file and we are flying blind.

You're asking for something standard. Something must be wrong with your command, but you didn't share the command, the CSV content, or the table definition.

Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the post!


Leave the defaults alone except for the delimiter which needs to be ;. 2) Make sure you selected csv as the format. 3) Make sure the number of fields being imported from the CSV match the number of fields in the table. The error indicates the server is getting more data in each row then the columns available in the table.


Thank you @AdrianKlaver! Leaving the default options (double-quotes for both Quote and Escape) and keeping the file as is (with the single-quotes) fixed the issue.

As to follow up question quote and escape are not meant to replace anything. The quote character is used to quote the entire data value, so in your case "sys='N/R'". escape escapes the quote, so if you had sys="N/R" and quote of " you would get "sys=""N/R""". Read COPY for more information.
